# How Do I Get A Value From MySQL Table - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables, fetch

I am having a real hard time fetching a value from my sql database. My code is below and I am trying to display $balance, but when I echo it, it just shows "Array".

Here is an image of my database table:
[image: database table]

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html><head><script src='OSC.js'></script>";
include 'functions.php';

$userstr = ' (Guest)';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $user     = $_SESSION['user'];
    $loggedin = TRUE;
    $userstr  = " ($user)";
    $balancequery = mysql_query("SELECT balance FROM members WHERE user = '$user'"); 
    $balance = mysql_fetch_assoc($balancequery); 
}
else $loggedin = FALSE;

echo "<title>$appname$userstr</title><link rel='stylesheet' " .
     "href='styles.css' type='text/css' />" .
     "</head><body><div class='appname'>$appname$userstr</div>";

if ($loggedin)
{
    echo "<br ><ul class='menu'>" .
         "<li><a href='members.php?view=$user'>Home</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='members.php'>Members</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='stockdata.php'>Stocks</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='logout.php'>Log out</a></li></ul><br />";
}
else
{
    echo ("<br /><ul class='menu'>" .
         "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='signup.php'>Sign up</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='login.php'>Log in</a></li></ul><br />" .
         "<span class='info'>&#8658; You must be logged in to " .
         "view this page.</span><br /><br />");
}
?>
```

Comment: What is print_r($balance) displaying you ? By the way, mysql_query is depreciated.

Comment: that's because $balance IS an array. try using print_r($balance) and see what comes out. and search for php arrays to learn how to echo a value from within the array.

Comment: @RelevantUsername that gave me "Array ( [balance] => 1000000 )"

Comment: @jimmy Why is this created as an array? Is there a way to just get the value itself?

Comment: Then access the value using $balance['balance'];

Comment: because mysql_fetch_assoc creates array. Yes there is a way, you should use ORM but in your script it's rather unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) returns an associative array of your fields for that row. To echo a field within that row, you must give it the proper index, which will be the name of the field:

```
echo $balance["balance"];
```

Also the mysql php extension is deprecated. Please look into [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to echo an associatove array, wich does not work. Try to print as value by indexing your array

```
echo $balance['balance'];  //this is just array_name['column_name']
```

I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).